# C# decrypting unknown encryption method

Tags: c#, encryption, arrays, bytebuffer

I want ask about decrypting method for my file
i already had C# program that give me some clue about decryption this file

here is some code for decryption:

```
string strFilePath = @"F:\Backup Data HDD\Data HDD (E)\project\dat\target_file.bin";
            sbyte num;
            int num3;
            sbyte num5;
            FileStream stream = File.OpenRead(strFilePath);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[stream.Length];
            stream.Read(buffer, 0, (int)stream.Length);
            stream.Close();
            int num2 = 72957;// 0x11cfd;
            int num4 = 0;
            for (num3 = 0; num3 != buffer.Length; num3++)
            {
                num = (sbyte)buffer[num3];
                num5 = num;
                num = (sbyte)(num ^ (num2 >> 8));
                num2 = ((num5 + num2) * 52845/*0xce6d*/) + 22719;//0x58bf;
                buffer[num3] = (byte)num;
            }
            MemoryStream input = new MemoryStream(buffer);
            BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(input);
            switch (this.m_Util.ByteArrayToString(reader.ReadBytes(64)))//0x40
            {
                case "ItemFile v5":
                    num4 = 5;
                    break;

                case "ItemFile v6":
                    num4 = 6;
                    break;

                case "ItemFile v7":
                    num4 = 7;
                    break;

                case "ItemFile v10":
                case "ItemFile v11":
                    num4 = 10;
                    break;
            }
```

I just confuse how to read the string under this file
because the switch case is working when i try to print it:

```
Console.Write(num4.toString());
```

it give me a number `10`
so the file is readable by this code and the code can read "Item File v10" or "Item File v11" because it return `10` when printed to console

but when i try to print this

```
Console.Write(this.m_Util.ByteArrayToString(reader.ReadBytes(64)));
```

it give me `È2` (ascii)
I'm beginner on C#
Can you help me ?
Thank you

Comment: You need to post enough code for us to compile and run it to be able to help. Right now a lot is hidden in the `this.m_Util` class and we just can't run it so we can't help.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your reply :) , the m_Util is under .dll library , can i give it for you ? :)

Comment: That would be great as long as you make sure we can run your code. That would mean providing the data too along with code we can run. If you're not able to do that then it wont help.

Comment: Now i can print that String, i just print it above switch case , but how i can get converted/ decrypted String , whole of file ? , the method is same , but above method just print "ItemFile v10", i think buffer size must bigger than before?

Comment: [link](http://sfh-seal.com/download_ss!/DecryptionProject.zip)
That's the file , maybe help :)

Comment: Sorry, but you're still a way away from us being able to run your code. The link you provided contains the app, but not the library. I appreciate that the dll is there, but it's not easy to see the code. I don't feel like I should decompile the code to get to it. Also you haven't provided the source data (bin file). You need to understand that SO is a fabulous resource for getting answers, but if you make your question a chore then most people will give up trying to answer. The fact that you've got no answers is an indication that your question needs improving.